# i can't use bitcoin-rpc library php

Tags: php, bitcoin

i install bitcoin-rpc in my vps google - ubuntu and conmandline: bitcoin-cli getinfo, result:

```
{
  "version": 120100,
  "protocolversion": 70012,
  "walletversion": 60000,
  "balance": 0.00000000,
  "blocks": 418298,
  "timeoffset": -37,
  "connections": 8,
  "proxy": "",
  "difficulty": 209453158595.381,
  "testnet": false,
  "keypoololdest": 1466760218,
  "keypoolsize": 10001,
  "paytxfee": 0.00000000,
  "relayfee": 0.00001000,
  "errors": ""
}
```

but my php code can't user function bitcoin, example:

```
require_once'jsonRPCClient.php';
    $Bitcoind->getaccountaddress($wallet_id);
    $Bytecoind->getaccountaddress($wallet_id);
...
```

nothing result with them, i try `var_dump('xxx');` after them but not displayed, all code after them not running, i don't know my vps lacking something, i installing this: https://github.com/zelles/BitcoinExchange. Help me please.

Comment: What happens when you run those functions?

Comment: nothing, them not running, and i try var_dump('xxx') after them but not displayed, all code after them not runing.

Comment: That sounds like there's an error sitting around in your server logs.